# Index Error when adding two items in a list

Tags: python

So, I have 8 randomly generated numbers, all referenced with `ct[i]`. I want to add a number (`ct[i]`) with the one referenced by `ct[i+1]`. However, this produces a list index out of range error. What's wrong?

```
for i in range(totrange):
    tot1 = ct[i] + ct[i+1]
```

`totrange` is usually 8, but I wanted to have a bit of flexibility.

Comment: So you're adding the last element in `ct` to... what? When `i` is `7` (which it will be if `totrange` is usually `8`), `ct[i+1]` will be out of bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use `range(len(ct)-1)` to handle this issue, as for the last `i`, `i+1` is a value which is greater than the last index of `ct`.

examples:

```
In [30]: ct=range(5)     #ct =[0,1,2,3,4]

In [31]: for i in range(len(ct)-1):
    print(ct[i]+ct[i+1])
   ....:     
1
3
5
7
```

or better use a `zip()` based solution, no need of using indexes at all:

```
In [32]: for x,y in zip(ct,ct[1:]):
    print (x+y)
   ....:     
1
3
5
7
```

Answer (score 1):

If `totrange` is 8 and `ct` contains 8 elements, the last `ct[i+1]` call will try to get the 9th element from `ct`, causing a list index out of range error.

Because of this, `totrange` should never be greater than `len(ct) - 1`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "`totrange` should never be greater than `len(ct)-1`" (so that `i` is never greater than `len(ct)-2`) ?

Comment: Nope. `len([0, 1])` is 2, which means that `(len([0, 1]) - 1) + 1` is 2, which is an index out of range. `(len([0, 1]) - 2) + 1` is 1 and will thus not be out of range.

Comment: You seem to be missing the `range(totrange)` part. If `totrange` is `len(ct)-1` (i.e. 7), `i` greatest value will be `6`, and `6+1` is a valid `ct` index.